# Removing locators breaks labels

Tags: graphics, dynamic, locator

I have some locators in a `LocatorPane` and want to let users remove them. Unfortunately, it seems doing this conflicts with the `Appearance` option.
Here's an example of the issue:

```
DynamicModule[{pts = {{-1, 1}/2, {1, 1}/2}, lbls = {"A", "B"}},
    Column @ {
         Dynamic @ pts, 
         LocatorPane[Dynamic @ pts, Framed @ Graphics @ {}, 
             LocatorAutoCreate -> {0, Length[pts]}, 
             Appearance -> lbls
         ]
     }
]
```

[image]

As you can see if hold the alt key (CMD on MacOS) and click on locator A, the label of the other locator *B is incorrectly changed to A*. Any simple workarounds to this?

**Analysis:**

This is the form of `LocatorPane` we're using:

[image]

According to the [docs](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LocatorPane.html), the option `LocatorAutoCreate` allows deletion of locators by CMD-clicking on them.

[image: ![![enter image description here]

I think that the proper index is deleted in first arg `Dynamic@pts` but the corresponding list of labels in the `Appearance` option is not (this I believe is the bug):

[image]

I'm not attached to using `LocatorPane`, perhaps `EventHandler` + `Locator`'s is a way to go?

Comment: Can everyone reproduce the above behavior? I’m on Mac 10.15.7 v12.1

Comment: This is normal behavior. Appearance is just a list used to display locators in the order they appear in pts. If the first locator is removed, the point disappears from pts, which will now contain only one point, to be associated with the first point in lbls.

Comment: If it’s not a bug it’s bad design, can you please think of a solution for my use case

Comment: @M.R. On Windows 10 version 12.1 this code calculates some expression so that we see on a screen different numbers like `{{-0.515,0.43},{0.55,0.45}}` not `{{-1/2,1/2},{1/2,1/2}}`. What actually do you try to reproduce with this code?

Comment: When you cmd click on A, B turns into A, I want to avoid that

Comment: @M.R. There is no this problem on Windows. Code works as expected.

Answer (score 5):

Does it fit your needs:

```
DynamicModule[{
  nodes = Transpose@{{{-1, 1}/2, {1, 1}/2}, {"A", "B"}}, length = 2
  }, Deploy@Column@{Dynamic@nodes[[All, 1]],
    Graphics[
     Dynamic[
      Table[myLocator[Dynamic @ nodes, i], {i, length}], 
      TrackedSymbols :> {length}
      ]
     , Frame -> True, PlotRange -> 1
     ]},
 Initialization :> (
   myLocator[Dynamic@nodes_, i_] := EventHandler[
     Inset[nodes[[i, 2]], Dynamic@nodes[[i, 1]]],
     {"MouseClicked" :> If[
        CurrentValue["AltKey"],
        nodes = Delete[nodes, i]; length = Length@nodes
        ]
      ,
      "MouseDragged" :> (
        nodes[[i, 1]] = CurrentValue[{"MousePosition", "Graphics"}]
        )
      },
     PassEventsDown -> True
     ]
   
   )]
```

Could probably be shorter with `Locator` instead of `MouseDragged` etc but I encountered a bug that prevented me from using `Locator`.

Comment: Nice, but this pinks for me in wolfram cloud

Comment: @M.R. ah, that's important piece, we can only count on LocatorPane there. I will try to look at it but I can't promise any timeframe.